# How to migrate Eclipse into android studio?

Tags: eclipse, android-studio

How do I translate this tutorial into android studio? http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/build-a-contacts-application-with-jquery-mobile-the-android-sdk-part-1--mobile-5727

Comment: @CrakC Android Studio is based on IntelliJ IDEA not Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the Eclipse project what you need to do:

1. Start Android Studio and close any open Android Studio projects.
2. From the Android Studio menu select File > New > Import Project. Alternatively, from the Welcome screen, select Import project (Eclipse ADT, Gradle, etc.).
3. Select the Eclipse ADT project folder with the AndroidManifest.xml file and click Ok.